# In a computational intensive system, could adding more nodes result in (near)linear performance increase?

Tags: performance, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, distributed-system, computation

Assuming a cluster of servers, doing computational intensive work.

Assuming there is NO DB, no file storage or anything of that sort in this system.

Assuming each node in the cluster is capable of computing alone.

Under those assumptions, could adding more nodes result in (near)linear performance increase?

If not, what are the constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, obviously it is **possible** to get a linear performance increase if there are no other limitations. You might be limited by the time a control node needs to divide the problem and merge the results, by communication between the nodes in general or by other factors.
Assuming you are already running your computations on a cluster you could run some benchmarks on different sub-sections of your cluster to get a curve of how your algorithm scales up to the number of nodes you already have. If the curve is still scaling linearly at the end you might assume that it will continue to do so for a while.

Depending on the algorithm it might even be possible that the performance increase is super-linear. This would be the case if memory access times are part of the bottleneck and by distributing the problem on more nodes each node needs to hold a smaller fraction of the whole working set in memory so you get less disk access, more cache hits and so on. This is probably rarely the case, though.